# How to replace a Dash/Plotly Table after it received new Data / or update the current Table

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

i want to build a DataTable which gets updated from time to time. Each time this happens, the table is supposed to fetch the data from a csv file. In order to do this i build a function that generates and returns the table. This works, after the second update - but the first table i generated stays and therefore i end up with to tables where one does what i want but the other one just stays...:

[The one on top is the second one, which updates. The one in the bottom is the on i generated first,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHZTc.png)

This is my code:

```
import random
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_table

import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('.../dummy2_csv.csv')


def maketable(dataf):
    tab = html.Div([dash_table.DataTable(
                id='adding-rows-table',
                editable=True,
                data=dataf.to_dict('rows'),
                columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in dataf.columns])])
    return tab


app = dash.Dash(__name__)


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id='my-div'),
    maketable(df),
    html.Button('+', id='editing-rows-button', n_clicks=0),
    html.Button('update', id='btn-save', n_clicks=0)
])



@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-div', component_property='children'),
    [Input('btn-save', 'n_clicks'), Input('adding-rows-table', 'data')]
)
def update_output_div(n_clicks, data):
    changed_id = [p['prop_id'] for p in dash.callback_context.triggered][0]
    if 'btn-save' in changed_id:
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

        for col in df2.columns:
            # new values
            df2[col].values[:] = random.randint(0,9)
        df2.to_csv('.../dummy2_csv.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
        return maketable(df2)


@app.callback(
    Output('adding-rows-table', 'data'),
    [Input('editing-rows-button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('adding-rows-table', 'data'),
     State('adding-rows-table', 'columns')])
def add_row(n_clicks, rows, columns):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        rows.append({c['id']: '' for c in columns})
    return rows


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

best, t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work

- the issue, was in callback function.

check:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_table
import dash_daq as daq
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('.../dummy2_csv.csv')

body = dbc.Container(
    [
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dash_table.DataTable(id="dash_neu", editable=True, row_deletable=True, columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns], data=df.to_dict('records')),
                dbc.Col(html.Button('+', id='editing-rows-button', n_clicks=0)),
                dbc.Col(html.Button('update', id='btn-save', n_clicks=0))
            ]
        )])

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div([body])


@app.callback(
    [dash.dependencies.Output("dash_neu", "data"), dash.dependencies.Output("dash_neu", "columns")],
    [Input("btn-save", "n_clicks"), Input('editing-rows-button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('dash_neu', 'data'), State('dash_neu', 'columns')]
)
def update(button, clicked, data, columns):
    changed_id = [p['prop_id'] for p in dash.callback_context.triggered][0]
    if 'btn-save' in changed_id:
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df.to_csv('.../dummy2_csv.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
        columns = [{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns]
        data = df.to_dict('records')
        return data, columns
    if 'editing-rows-button' in changed_id:
        if clicked > 0:
             data.append({c['id']: '' for c in columns})
        return data, columns
    return data, columns
```

Comment: Great job figuring it out! Can you include a little more explanation of what you changed that resolved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is because you've called the function to build the table outside of the `div` which receives the table from your callback. Try changing your layout to this:

```py
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id='my-div', children=[maketable(df)]),
    html.Button('+', id='editing-rows-button', n_clicks=0),
    html.Button('update', id='btn-save', n_clicks=0)
])
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not work :(

but i'll try to include your help to fix it!
- thx!